# In what order does the Components are drawn in XNA4 Game Class?

Tags: .net-4.0, components, drawable, xna-4.0

I'm creating a Bomberman Game with different Components. I've created separate `DrawableGameComponents` for `BombList`, `PlayerList`, `WallList`, `PlayerDisplay (List of players when TAB is pressed)` and added them in the `Components` list. The backboard and instruction texts are drawn in the main `Game1` class.

I want to know in what order these Components are rendered. Is it in the order in which they are in `Components` List? Initially it seemed like that.

Later, I needed to update `BombList`, `PlayerList` and `WallList`. But this time, it was rendering `PlayersDisplay` at the back. I tried to insert them at different positions but I realized what matters is the order in which the Components are added (no matter at what position).

My questions are

- **In what order are the Components rendered in `Components` list?**
- **If I've many Components, then when will the `Draw()` of the `Game1` class be called with respect to other Components in the list?**
- **Has this `Game` class been added in the `Components` list in the base constructor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading up on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent_members.aspx) explains that.

It has the following member: `.DrawOrder`

> Order in which the component should be drawn, relative to other components that are in the same GameComponentCollection.

Additionally, when you call `base.Draw()` in your `Draw` override you're calling the `.Draw` method for all components.